# Cython actually slowing me down

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am trying to 'cythonize' my code however while the following code does work, it is not adding any speed to my code (in fact its a shade slower). I am wondering if anyone knows what I am doing wrong if anything at all. Note I am passing a numpy array and its data type should be float16. Never used cython before and I am using Jupyter notebook right now.  In the cell above I have Cython loaded.

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

DTYPE = np.float16
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t

def arrange_waveforms(np.ndarray arr,dim,mintomaxEventslistrange):
    import timeit
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    cdef int key
    #mintomaxEventslistrange is basically range(2000000)
    dictlist = dict((key,  [[] for _ in xrange(1536)]) for key in mintomaxEventslistrange)      
# A seperate one to hold the timing info (did this to minimize memory of dictlist)
    window = dict((key,  [[] for _ in xrange(1536)]) for key in mintomaxEventslistrange)
#arrange waveforms
    cdef np.ndarray pixel=arr[:,0].astype(int)
    cdef int i
    cdef int lines = dim[0]
    for i in range(lines):

        dictlist[arr[i,1]][pixel[i]].extend(arr[i,9:])
        window[arr[i,1]][pixel[i]].append(arr[i,6]) 
    elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
    print elapsed
    return dictlist,window
```

Comment: `cdef int Eventsrange`...`for key in Eventsrange`??? Anyway, Cython isn't going to help if you keep using the Python half, eg. `dict`s and generator expressions. You need to use fast types to get speed improvements.

Comment: That was an error sorry.  So even in my for loop it will not help me? The loop is composed of  approximately two million iterations. (lines~2,000000). To be fair you are right, it has not helped me at all. First time I have used Cython so I'm in the dark.

Comment: It can help, but you need to help it help you. You should use `cdef int64_t[:] pixel = ...` to type the Numpy array and probably turn `dictlist` and `window` into Numpy arrays too.

Comment: `cython` gains speed when it can transform the loop into pure C code.  It can't do that with those dict and list operations in your loop.  Go back to your Python code and make sure that is running efficiently.  Then identify a small piece that is taking up too much time - code just that for `cython`.  It can speed up `numpy` operations better than list/dictionary ones.  Leave all the timing baggage in Python.